# how to suppress exit 0 from previous command?

Tags: powershell

I have two powershell scripts.

script1 is a script that is supposed to be a wrapper and passes parameters to script2. script2 generates data based on those passed parameters.

script1 has currently a for loop the iterates a command like this:

```
foreach()
{   
    cmd /c "openPS.bat script2.ps1 $($someParam[-1])"
}
```

everytime that command runs successfully, it outputs exit 0

[image: exit0]

as you can see, in one of the runs, there was an error in script2 in which i specified to output `exit 1 + $error[0]` whenever there is an error/exception. but nowhere in script2 did i specify exit 0. there is only for exit 1 (error).

i read suggestions to use `| out-null` after the command, but the problem is the error from script2 no longer gets outputted/reported.

can i say something like `cmd /c "openPS.bat script2.ps1 $($someParam[-1]) | out-null only exit 0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if((cmd /c "openPS.bat script2.ps1 $($someParam[-1])") -match "0"){Out-Null}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is much better to explain how it answers the question.